# Python3 - web scraping zomato - multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can't seem to generate output for anything beyond page 1 (one page has 15 restaurants and that's all I am getting (just 15 output). It looks like the output from page one gets replaced by page two and so forth.

I have tried adding in the page range to **scrape** but still came back with only 15 results (**scraping** only just one page).

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

for num in range(1,5):
    url = 'https://www.zomato.com/auckland/restaurants?gold_partner=1&page={}'.format(num)
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

top_rest = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "col-s-16 search_results mbot"})
list_tr = top_rest[0].find_all("div",attrs={"class": "js-search-result-li even status 1"})
list_rest =[]

for tr in list_tr:
    dataframe ={}
    dataframe["1.rest_name"] = (tr.find("a",attrs={"class": "result-title hover_feedback zred bold ln24 fontsize0"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    dataframe["2.rest_address"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "col-m-16 search-result-address grey-text nowrap ln22"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    list_rest.append(dataframe)
    list_rest

df = pandas.DataFrame(list_rest)
df.to_csv("zomato_res26.csv",index=False)
```

I expect to get a list of output of 40+ restaurants with their names and location, but so far it looks like I'm only getting 15 restaurants per page where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the indentation and move the list creation,  `list_rest`,  out of the loop and append to it in the loop. Also, change the encoding for output to `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to properly handle the characters present. You can get the number of pages with `int(soup.select_one('.pagination-number b:last-child').text)` .

I've also added `requests.Session()` to re-use connection.

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

list_rest =[]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for num in range(1,5):
        url = 'https://www.zomato.com/auckland/restaurants?gold_partner=1&page={}'.format(num)
        response = s.get(url,headers=headers)
        content = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

        top_rest = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "col-s-16 search_results mbot"})
        list_tr = top_rest[0].find_all("div",attrs={"class": "js-search-result-li even status 1"})

        for tr in list_tr:
            dataframe ={}
            dataframe["1.rest_name"] = (tr.find("a",attrs={"class": "result-title hover_feedback zred bold ln24 fontsize0"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
            dataframe["2.rest_address"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "col-m-16 search-result-address grey-text nowrap ln22"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
            list_rest.append(dataframe)

df = pandas.DataFrame(list_rest)
df.to_csv(r"zomato_res26.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

If you want to loop all pages and use faster selectors with list comprehensions:

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

list_rest =[]

def getInfo(soup):
    names = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.result-title')]
    addresses =  [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.search-result-address')]
    row = list(zip(names, addresses))
    return row

with requests.Session() as s:   
        url = 'https://www.zomato.com/auckland/restaurants?gold_partner=1&page={}'
        response = s.get(url.format(1),headers=headers)
        content = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
        numPages = int(soup.select_one('.pagination-number b:last-child').text)
        list_rest.append(getInfo(soup))

        if numPages > 1:
            for page in range(2, numPages + 1):
                response = s.get(url.format(page),headers=headers)
                content = response.content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
                list_rest.append(getInfo(soup))

final_list = [item for sublist in list_rest for item in sublist]
df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['1.rest_name', '2.rest_address'])
df.to_csv(r"zomato_res26.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, tested the code and it worked! Will need to take a closer look to learn the structure of it, once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What if you don't know the last page number!!! The following script will take care of that pagination thing. It will parse the last page number and then create a loop to traverse them in order to fetch restaurant names and their concerning phone numbers.

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zomato.com/auckland/restaurants?gold_partner=1&page="

def get_content(session,link):
    session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    response = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    dataframe = []
    last_page = soup.select_one(".pagination-number b:nth-of-type(2)").text
    for item_url in range(1,int(last_page)+1):
        res = session.get(f"{link}{item_url}")
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for elem in sauce.select(".search-card"):
            d = {}
            d['name'] = elem.select_one("a[data-result-type='ResCard_Name']").get_text(strip=True)
            d['phone'] = elem.select_one("a.res-snippet-ph-info").get("data-phone-no-str")
            dataframe.append(d)

    return dataframe

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        item = get_content(session,url)
        df = pandas.DataFrame(item)
        df.to_csv("zomato_res26.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: I will definitely need to implement this as I assume I won't always be able to determine the last content page. Thanks again!